# combine two column and create new column using pandas library

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv("school_data.csv")

    col1    col2 
0  [1,2,3]  [4,5,6] 
1  [0,5,3]  [6,2,5]
```

want o/p

```
    col1    col2      col3
0  [1,2,3]  [4,5,6]   [1,2,3,4,5,6]
1  [0,5,3]  [6,2,5]   [0,5,3,6,2,5]
```

col1 and col2 value are unique,
using pandas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest way would be to do this:

```
df['col3'] = df['col1'] + df['col2']
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd


row1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
row2 = [[0,5,3], [6,2,5]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[row1, row2], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
df['col3'] = df['col1'] + df['col2']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        col1       col2                col3
0  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6]  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
1  [0, 5, 3]  [6, 2, 5]  [0, 5, 3, 6, 2, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply function on more than one column at once, like this:

```
def func(x):
    return x['col1'] + x['col2']

df['col3'] = df[['col1','col2']].apply(func, axis=1)
```

Why not do a simple `df['col1']` + `df['col2']`?

Assume `col1` has `list` but in `str` types. In that case you can always modify `func` to:

```
def func(x):
    return x['col1'][1:-1].split(',') + x['col2']
```